react-sigma / sigmaJS example using a force layout?
I'm trying to find a simple example of how to use sigmaJS in react with a force layout.
Most of the examples seem broken across multiple files.
The docs hint at layouts but are incomplete.
I was looking at this example which is in storybook which seems a completely different way of managing than the react-sigma examples. Using a custom JS render loop and useRef.
Should I just avoid react-sigma and use the raw sigmaJS library if I need a layout?
I got somewhere with this but got stuck in how to have a second component to handle the animation worker. Putting the code I have so far below but i've iterated a few times and can't get the layout to animate or apply.
Just looking for a simple react-sigma example that is complete and working
/**
 * https://github.com/sim51/react-sigma/blob/e6528da2c1fa6f11413366f05bd6fd547f940f03/packages/storybook/stories/LayoutFA2.tsx
 * https://www.sigmajs.org/storybook/?path=/story/layouts--story
 */

import { CSSProperties, FC, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { SigmaContainer, useLoadGraph } from "@react-sigma/core";
import "@react-sigma/core/lib/react-sigma.min.css";
import { DirectedGraph } from "graphology";
import FA2Layout from "graphology-layout-forceatlas2/worker";
import forceAtlas2 from "graphology-layout-forceatlas2";
import forceLayout from 'graphology-layout-force';
import sigma from 'sigma';

// import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectStory, selectChapter, setStory } from "../../redux/semSlice"
import ForceSupervisor from "graphology-layout-force/worker";

import { SemData } from "../../types/sharedTypes/SemTypes";
import Graph from "graphology";
import { useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
// import { selectChapter } from "../../redux/chapterSlice";

const sigmaStyle: CSSProperties = {
  right: '0px',
  top: '0px',
  position: "fixed",
  height: "500px",
  width: "500px"
};

// Component that load the graph
export const LoadGraph = () => {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);

  // const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const semData = useLoaderData() as SemData
  const story = semData
  const chapter = useSelector(selectChapter)
  // const story = useSelector(selectStory)
  // if (semData) {
  //   dispatch(setStory(semData))
  // }
  // const story: SemData | undefined = useSelector(selectStory)
  // if (!story?.graph) return null;

  const loadGraph = useLoadGraph();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('LoadGraph / chapter', chapter)

    // const graphData = { ...story?.graph } // unfreeze
    const graphData = chapter?.graph // unfreeze
    if (!graphData) return;
    console.log('graphData', graphData)

    const graph = new Graph();

    graphData.nodes.forEach((node) => {
      const n = ({
        ...node,
        size: 10,
        x: Math.random(),
        y: Math.random(),
        label: node.key
      });
      console.log('n', n)
      graph.addNode(n.key, n);
    })
    graphData.edges.forEach((edge) => {
      const props = {
        label: edge.attributes?.type,
        size: 5,
      };
      console.log('edge', edge)
      graph.addEdge(edge.source, edge.target, props);
    })
    console.log('graph.json', graph.toJSON())

    // const sigmaInstance = new sigma(
    //   graph,
    //   containerRef.current
    // );

    // sigmaInstance.refresh();

    // return () => {
    //   sigmaInstance.kill();
    // };

    loadGraph(graph);

    // const positions = forceLayout(graph, {
    //   maxIterations: 50,
    //   settings: {
    //     gravity: 10
    //   }
    // });

    // To directly assign the positions to the nodes:
    // forceLayout.assign(graph, 50);

    // const sensibleSettings = forceAtlas2.inferSettings(graph);
    // const fa2Layout = new FA2Layout(graph, {
    //   settings: sensibleSettings,
    // });
    // fa2Layout.start();

    // return () => {
    //   // clean up
    //   fa2Layout.stop();
    // }


    // const layout = new ForceSupervisor(graph);
    // layout.start();

  }, [chapter, loadGraph]);

  return (
    <div ref={containerRef} style={{ width: '100%', height: '400px' }} />
  )

  // return null;
};

// // needs the graph object passed in?
// const AnimateGraph: FC = (props: any) => {
//   // const { start, kill } = useWorkerLayoutForceAtlas2({ settings: { slowDown: 10 } });

//   useEffect(() => {
//     // start();
//     const layout = new ForceSupervisor(props.graph);
//     // start FA2
//     layout.start();

//     // Kill FA2 on unmount
//     return () => {
//       layout.kill();
//     };
//   }, [props.graph]);

//   return null;
// };


// Component that display the graph
export const SemGraphBase = () => {

  return (
    <SigmaContainer style={sigmaStyle}>
      <LoadGraph />

    </SigmaContainer>
  );
};


The storybook examples in sigma are plain old javascript.
Of course you can use them in your web project.
For react, I created the the lib you mention (ie @react-sigma), and it's the standard way to use sigma within react (mainly for the container with the sigmajs lifecycle).
About the layout, the lib provides some helpers which are usefull specially for layouts with a worker. But if you want, you can directly use the graphology layout you want and apply it on the graph.
You should take a look at this example https://sim51.github.io/react-sigma/storybook/index.html?path=/story/layout-fa2-control--default  in the storybook, which for my point of view is simple :
import { FC, CSSProperties } from "react";

import "@react-sigma/core/lib/react-sigma.min.css";
import { SigmaContainer, ControlsContainer } from "@react-sigma/core";
import { LayoutForceAtlas2Control } from "@react-sigma/layout-forceatlas2";
import "@react-sigma/core/lib/react-sigma.min.css";


const SampleGraph: FC<unknown> = ({) => {
  const loadGraph = useLoadGraph();

  useEffect(()=> {
    // Create you graph 
    const graph = new Graph();
    ...
    loadGraph(graph);

  }, [loadGraph]);
}

export const MySigmaGraph: FC<{ style: CSSProperties }> = ({ style }) => {
  return (
    <SigmaContainer style={style} settings={{ allowInvalidContainer: true }}>
      <SampleGraph />
      <ControlsContainer position={"bottom-right"}>
        <LayoutForceAtlas2Control />
      </ControlsContainer>
    </SigmaContainer>
  );
};

BTW, if you don't like the approach to create "controller component" like the SampleGraph, you can directly create a graph and give it directly to the SigmaContainer :
import { FC, CSSProperties } from "react";
import Graph from "graphology";

import "@react-sigma/core/lib/react-sigma.min.css";
import { SigmaContainer, ControlsContainer } from "@react-sigma/core";
import { LayoutForceAtlas2Control } from "@react-sigma/layout-forceatlas2";
import "@react-sigma/core/lib/react-sigma.min.css";

export const MySigmaGraph: FC<{ style: CSSProperties }> = ({ style }) => {
 const  [graph, setGraph] = useState<Graph>(new Graph());

 useEffect(()=> {
   // Create you graph 
   const graph = new Graph();
   ...
   setGraph(graph);

 }, []);

 return (
   <SigmaContainer graph={graph settings={{ allowInvalidContainer: true }}>
     <ControlsContainer position={"bottom-right"}>
       <LayoutForceAtlas2Control />
     </ControlsContainer>
   </SigmaContainer>
 );
}

And if you have ideas on how to make doc better, I will be glad to know them! You can create a ticket for any suggestions.
